# Using foreach instead of for loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach

I am trying to learn `foreach` to parallelise my task

My for-loop looks like this:

```
     # create an empty matrix to store results
     mat <- matrix(-9999, nrow = unique(dat$mun), ncol = 2)

     for(mun in unique(dat$mun)) {

           dat <- read.csv(paste0("data",mun,".csv")
           tot.dat <- sum(dat$x)
           mat[mat[,1]== mun,2] <- tot.dat
     }
```

`unique(dat$mun)` has a length of 5563.

I want to use `foreach` to pararellise my task.

```
      library(foreach)
      library(doParallel)

      # number of iterations
      iters <- 5563

      foreach(icount(iters)) %dopar% {
          mun <- unique(dat$mun)[mun] # this is where I cannot figure out how to assing mun so that it read the data for mun

          dat <- read.csv(paste0("data",mun,".csv")
          tot.dat <- sum(dat$x)
          mat[mat[,1]== mun,2] <- tot.dat
        }
```

Comment: Have you read the package vignettes? `foreach` loops are fundamentally different from `for` loops. Most importantly, they can't have side effects (at least when used for parallelization). This means you can't assign into an object outside the loop (like `mat`) from inside the loop. Anyway, you can simply do `foreach(mun =  unique(dat$mun))`.

Comment: Also, there is a good chance that `read.csv` is what takes most of the time. If so, consider using `fread` from package data.table (the "f" stands for "fast"). It might be many orders of magnitude faster and you possibly wouldn't need parallelization.

Comment: In addition to @Roland suggestion to use `fread`, I'm not convinced this is a good candidate for parallelization in any case, as each for loop requires a file read.  Doing these tasks in parallel could very easily lead to more disk seeks, and thus slower rather than faster operation.

Comment: okay. Thank you for your suggestions. I will read more around it.

Answer (score -1):

This could be one solution.
Do note that I'm using windows here, and i specified `registerDoParallel()` for it to work.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# number of iterations
iters <- 5563

registerDoParallel()
mun <- unique(dat$mun)

tableList <- foreach(i=1:iters) %dopar% {
  dat <- read.csv(paste0("data",mun[i],".csv")
  tot.dat <- sum(dat$x)
}
unlist(tableList)
```

Essentially, whatever result inside `{...}` will be stored inside a list.
In this case, the result (`tot.dat` which is a number) is compiled in `tableList`, and by performing `unlist()` we can convert it to a vector for further use.

The result inside `{...}` can be anything, a single number, a vector, a dataframe, or anything.
Another approach for your problem would be to combine all existing data together, labelling it with its appropriate source file, so the middle component will look something like

```
library(plyr)
tableAll <- foreach(i=1:iters) %dopar% {
  dat <- read.csv(paste0("data",mun[i],".csv")
  dat$source = mun[i]
}
rbind.fill(tableAll)
```

Then we can use it for further analysis.